# The intersection of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ is trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ the space of sequences with entries in $F$ and $S$ the linear operator of $W$ given by: $$S(a_1,a_2,a_3,...) = (a_2,a_3,...)$$

We know that if  the intersection of $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ is trivial then the vector space is direct sum of these two subspaces, but in this example how can i prove that $W$ in the sum of $\operatorname{Im}(S)$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(s)$ but is not direct sum, some help please.

Comment: Showing that $S$ is surjective would be a good start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show $im (T)\cap \ker T\neq 0$. Try $(1,0,0\ldots)$.